# Simulator doesn't added to the simulators list in the xCode. How to add simulator to the Xcode 11?

Tags: xcode, xcode11

I try to add a simulator with 10.3 iOS to the Xcode 11.3.1, but can't:

- I'm installed iOS 10.3 and created new simulator:

[image]

And this simulator was successfully added in the general list:

[image]

But for the project this simulator wasn't created:

[image]

---

How to add a simulator to the project and launch it?

Comment: Make sure your deployment target is lower or equal to the desired simulator version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change Target value for you project

[target value location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M4vw.png)